# How to assign a value of 0 if a row doesn't meet the requirements

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to return an actor name field (A_Name) and the movie role field (MR_Role) with the number of times each actor has an "Uncredited" in their role. I also want to return a 0 if that specific actor does not have an "Uncredited" in their role. You'll see in my table formats there's another table, but I don't need to use it to run this query since that just has movie id and year of release.

I've used this code to return the amount of uncredited roles for each actor, but without the 0's:

```
SELECT A_NAME, COUNT(MR_ROLE) 
FROM ACTOR JOIN MOVIEROLE ON ACTOR.A_ID = MOVIEROLE.A_ID 
WHERE MOVIEROLE.MR_ROLE LIKE '%UNCREDITED%'
GROUP BY A_NAME;
```

[Here are the results from the above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh0aV.png)

These are the formats of the tables I'm using:

```
ACTOR TABLE:

 (A_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,      
  A_NAME CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  A_YOB INTEGER NOT NULL,)

MOVIEROLE TABLE:

(MR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,      
  A_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  M_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  MR_ROLE CHAR(45),  
  PRIMARY KEY (MR_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(A_ID) REFERENCES ACTOR,
  FOREIGN KEY(M_ID) REFERENCES MOVIE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` to return the `0`s:

```
SELECT a.A_NAME, COUNT(mr.MR_ROLE) 
FROM ACTOR a LEFT JOIN
     MOVIEROLE mr
     ON a.A_ID = mr.A_ID AND
        mr.MR_ROLE LIKE '%UNCREDITED%'
GROUP BY a.A_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the conding in the `where` clause, you could move it to a `case` expression inside the `count` function, and utilize the fact that `count` skips `null`s:

```
SELECT   A_NAME, COUNT(CASE WHEN MR_ROLE LIKE '%UNCREDITED%' THEN 1 END) 
FROM     ACTOR
JOIN     MOVIEROLE ON ACTOR.A_ID = MOVIEROLE.A_ID
GROUP BY A_NAME;
```